# Which function in pascal is the fastest one, while, for or repeat?

Tags: performance, pascal

I solved one problem in pascal using mostly for function and I didn't meet the time limit, and the problems is correctly solver in the best way. So is any of these other functions faster maybe or I made a mistake and solved it wrongly?

Comment: You could answer your own question with a benchmark. If you post your code, maybe someone can help you figure out what's slowing you down.

Comment: try both and disassemble.  not a globally true answer any more than benchmarking, but you can see that on your platform with that compiler it does or doesnt make different code.

Comment: Give us some code. Might get you better chances to get help (and a better rating)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Try out! just make 3 versions of your solution and test each against a good mass  data and record how much times it takes. If you are still not getting the time limit you want try a faster PC or review your solution.

Answer (score 1):

`while` and `repeat` are not functions, but indicate looping control structures intrinsic to the programming language.

Neither is faster, neither is slower. Both are faster, both are slower. A general answer is not possible, and the more work you do inside the loop, the less relevant any difference, if any, becomes.

If you didn't solve your exercise, then the problem is not the choice of the loop. It could be the algorithm you chose, it could be a mistake you made, it could be the testing machine didn't have enough processing time left to your program to be in time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a sensible compiler, there should be no performance difference between them.

Even if there were a difference, it would likely be negligible -- unnoticeable by humans, and easily within experimental error for computed results.

Since this is a school assignment, I'd suggest reviewing the material taught in the last week; probably something there will hint at a better way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, for was considered faster, because it didn't allow changing the loop variable , which enabled certain kind of optimizations, specially if the value of the loop variable wasn't used.

Nowadays, with less memory and time limits on optimization, the various forms are easily transformed into each other, and the whole discussion becomes academic.

Note that most modern compilers (after Delphi) add another check to the FOR statement, to check that the higher bound is greater or equal than the lower bound. If you have to answer such question for homework, check your compiler very thoroughly.